# cannot able to find the md5_file value for a remote file

Tags: php, networking

I am trying to find the md5_file value for a file that is placed in a remote system and trying to update that value in my database. I have tried using md5_file('http://..../$remote_file'), but I am getting nothing. If there is any network configuration is needed to read the remote files. My application is using php5 and firefox 15. could anybody tell some other way to find this

Comment: You you can raise the error level by putting the following PHP code on top of your script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(~0);` That should give you also more information. Also take care that variable substitution only works in double quoted strings (double check the URL is literally correct and does not contain any $ sign or similiar).

Answer (score 1):

Like many other functions in PHP, [`md5_file`](http://php.net/md5_file) returns `FALSE` on error.

In your case I would first of all check if your function returns `FALSE`, which sometimes is similar to *"getting nothing"*:

```
$url = 'http://..../$remote_file';
$md5 = md5_file($url);
if ($md5 === FALSE) {
    die("Error retrieving md5 from $url.");
}
```

Change your code and see the outcome. You will stumble over a detail you will identify as the cause of your error then I assume. That should allow you to fix it easily.

Comment: Its showing the correct url but still not able to calculate the md5_file()